# Does the Android SQLite implementation sanitize input via the SQLiteDatabase.insert() method?

Tags: android, sqlite, input

The [SQLiteDataBase.insert(String, String, ContentValues)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) convenience method takes a `ContentValues` object which contains all of the column values of a row to be inserted into the database. If I use the `ContentValues.put()` methods to build a `ContentValues` object to insert into the database, does either `put()` or `insert()` sanitize the input or do I have to do that myself?

Comment: Sorry about the bung hyperlinking but it always works in the preview and never in the real post for me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this will protect you from injection.  You can see in the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2.2_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java#SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Candroid.content.ContentValues%2Cint%29) that `insertWithOnConflict` (which is called by `insert`) correctly uses `?` place-holders in a `SQLiteStatement`.

Comment: That link appears to be broken, the page says "Unknown identifier: "android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java". Falling back to search"

Answer (score 0):

%W will sanitize it with double quotes, but how much sanitation are you wanting?